# Activating extension failed: Cannot find module 'glob'

Tags: npm, vscode-extensions, glob

Developing a VS Code extension. When testing the extension locally in my developer window, everything works perfectly. But when I publish the extension in the marketplace, I get an error saying:

```
mainThreadExtensionService.ts:112 Activating extension 'Massdriver.vscode-massdriver-tools' failed: Cannot find module 'glob'
Require stack:
- /home/michael/.vscode-server/extensions/test.vscode-ex-tools-0.0.4/out/terraform/deploy.js
- /home/michael/.vscode-server/extensions/test.vscode-ex-tools-0.0.4/out/extension.js
- /home/michael/.vscode-server/bin/7f329fe6c66b0f86ae1574c2911b681ad5a45d63/out/vs/loader.js
- /home/michael/.vscode-server/bin/7f329fe6c66b0f86ae1574c2911b681ad5a45d63/out/bootstrap-amd.js
- /home/michael/.vscode-server/bin/7f329fe6c66b0f86ae1574c2911b681ad5a45d63/out/bootstrap-fork.js.
```

I also get a popup error saying:

```
Command 'Ex:Action One' resulted in an error
command 'ex:actionone' not found
```

This is my `package.json` dependencies:

```
  "scripts": {
    "vscode:prepublish": "npm run compile",
    "compile": "tsc -p ./",
    "watch": "tsc -watch -p ./",
    "pretest": "npm run compile && npm run lint",
    "lint": "eslint src --ext ts",
    "test": "node ./out/test/runTest.js"
  },
  "dependencies": {
    "fs": "^0.0.1-security",
    "path": "^0.12.7",
    "semver": "^7.3.8",
    "glob": "^10.0.0"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "@types/glob": "^8.0.0",
    "@types/mocha": "^10.0.0",
    "@types/node": "16.x",
    "@types/vscode": "^1.72.0",
    "@typescript-eslint/eslint-plugin": "^5.38.1",
    "@typescript-eslint/parser": "^5.38.1",
    "@vscode/test-electron": "^2.1.5",
    "eslint": "^8.26.0",
    "glob": "^10.0.0",
    "typescript": "^4.8.4"
  }
```

Here is my tsconfig.json

```
{
    "compilerOptions": {
        "module": "commonjs",
        "target": "ES2020",
        "outDir": "out",
        "lib": [
            "ES2020"
        ],
        "sourceMap": true,
        "rootDir": "src",
        "strict": true,
        "esModuleInterop": true,
        "skipLibCheck": true 
        /* enable all strict type-checking options */
        /* Additional Checks */
        // "noImplicitReturns": true, /* Report error when not all code paths in function return a value. */
        // "noFallthroughCasesInSwitch": true, /* Report errors for fallthrough cases in switch statement. */
        // "noUnusedParameters": true,  /* Report errors on unused parameters. */
    },
    "exclude": [
        "node_modules",
        ".vscode-test"
    ]
}
```

I tried running various commands like `npm install glob` or `npm install --save-dev glob`. I've tried deleting and recreating `node_modules` directory. I've tried uninstalling and reinstalling npm.

Answer (score 2):

Had the same issue: Removing glob from **devDependencies** solved it for me.

Normally, having the same library with the same version in both dependencies and devDependencies shouldn't cause any problems but in this particular case it does for some reason.

Answer (score 0):

npm install --force should fix this issue